# How long does it take to get the registration certificate or residence card as the family member of a European Economic Area?

Tags: united-kingdom

Do you know how long does it take to get the "registration certificate or residence card as the family member of a European Economic Area (EEA) or Swiss national" I have collected very useful information from your answers and from the official UK immigration website. However, I haven't found information related to the time it takes to get the actual residence card. Also, I would like to know whether I can process this application as soon as I get to the UK.

I can prove all what is requested as my husband will have a permanent contract. Basically, what worries me is that I don't know how long I will have to wait before I can start working again.

Comment: The theory (and actual practice in other countries) is that you get some sort  of receipt or certificate valid for a few months immediately and an actual card once everything is processed. But since you have to apply by post in the UK, I am not sure how it works there (+1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In response to your question, EU residence card applications usually takes maximum 6 months to process, however when you submit your application to the Home Office, they normally issue a letter confirming your application and giving you a document to confirm your rights to live and work in the UK. That document can be used to show to your employers that you have permission to work.

Remember that your husband must be employed prior to the date of application.

Further to that, as soon as you enter the UK, you can submit your application for the EU residence card. You do not need to wait any time, however as long as you apply before your EU family permit expires, then that is fine also.